# jQuery parseJSON object question/issue

Tags: jquery, python, json

I've been playing around with jQuery's parseJSON and simplejson and I can't seem to figure out why I'm unable to get my variables to print or compare.

I know my Python return statement is correct, because if it wasn't the jQuery.ajax would return false and the "error" code would run.  So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong with the jQuery

Here's the code I'm trying to use:

Pythong/Django return statement...

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'result': True}), mimetype='application/json')
```

jQuery/javascript...  (.ajax function... i just left in the good parts)

```
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
              jQuery(".signup").attr('disabled', false);
              //parse return data
              var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
              if(obj.result == true){
                //$('.signup-area .heading').hide();
                //$('#signup').hide();
                $('.success').show().append(obj.result);
              }
              else{
                $('.signup-area .heading').hide();
                $('#signup').hide();
                $('.success').show().append('in the else');
              }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              jQuery(".signup").attr('disabled', false);
              $('.fail').show().append(errorThrown);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the jQuery ajax function takes is 'dataType' parameter which you can specify 'json' so that jQuery will automatically parse the data. In that case you dont have to call parseJson in order to get response as json.

Something like

jQuery.ajax({

url:url,

**dataType:'json'**,

success:function(data){

//data will be in json format so no need to parse it again.

},

error:function(){}
});

I hope this helps.

Comment: (i didn't know it automatically parsed it.. i just thought it checked to make sure it was in json format)

Comment: i just checked the jQuery page on ajax dataType parameter http://docs.jquery.com/Specifying_the_Data_Type_for_AJAX_Requests. it says **...jQuery will take the responseText of the XMLHttpRequest, and turn it into an object and pass**

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem recently and it was because I was using single quotes in my JSON, which parseJSON considers invalid.

```
$.parseJSON("{'key':'value'}")
Invalid JSON: {'key':'value'}
$.parseJSON('{"key":"value"}')
Object
```

The way I figured this out was to call parseJSON from the JS console window in chrome. I then verified this was the issue by running my JSON through [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: weird... that actually worked.That doesn't make any sense though.  Isn't json.dumps() supposed to reformat the single and double quotes anyway?

Comment: sorry, what worked? you mean replacing the single quotes with doubles fixed the problem? json.dumps should be doing the replacement for you, although you can verify this for yourself.

Comment: yeah using your second example worked, but it doesn't work with True False still for whatever reason.  unless they need to be put inside quotes as well.

Comment: I also had to set my .ajax to dataType: "text json" instead of just json.. which i also found weird.

Comment: one more thing to add... I did test json.dumps and it fixes all of the quotes correctly.. so I'm not sure why .parseJSON() doesn't like it.

Comment: chris, try logging the exact json you are getting back from your server with javascript console.log or alert. then put that JSON through the JSONLint link I sent, and see what it says. that should help you track down where the problem is.